# Add seconds ":00" to a character string if missing

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I have a dataset example, where I want to use lapply (or any other members of apply family) to paste two variables together, where specific condition applies.

Dataframe example:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c('8','5','8','8','5','8'), 
v2=c('20:05:20','19:20','15:37:35','12:04:21','12:45','13:08:21'))

  v1       v2
1  8 20:05:20
2  5    19:20
3  8 15:37:35
4  8 12:04:21
5  5    12:45
6  8 13:08:21
```

I managed to solve my problem with code below, where I use lapply to write `:00` in `add` variable and then I paste them both together in `v3` variable.

```
df$add <- lapply(df$v1, function(x) if (x == 5) {paste(":00")} else {""})
df$v3 <- paste(df$v2,df$add, sep="")

  v1       v2 add       v3
1  8 20:05:20     20:05:20
2  5    19:20 :00 19:20:00
3  8 15:37:35     15:37:35
4  8 12:04:21     12:04:21
5  5    12:45 :00 12:45:00
6  8 13:08:21     13:08:21
```

I am looking for a solution to do all of this in one line of code - specifically I want to use lapply and add values from `v2` already at combining / pasting with missing `:00`.

Comment: I do understand there are many solutions to this problem, however this is not the case. I am particularly interested in solution, where I am using one of `apply`-es and where within function I am referencing to using another variable (not x) in data frame and changing value in this another variable right at all x-indexes. I hope this is clear.

Comment: to use `apply` simply take the solution from @PoGibas and put it after the `function(x)` part of your code. Have a look at `dplyr` and pipes `%>%`, you can use the `mutate` function to have the same result. There are many options for results.

Comment: @gaspers I edited my answer with `apply` family solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using substitution (`sub`):

```
df$v3 <- sub("^([0-9]+:[0-9]+)$", "\\1:00", df$v2)
[1] "20:05:20" "19:20:00" "15:37:35" "12:04:21" "12:45:00" "13:08:21"
```

Instead of looping substitute pattern: `digits:digits` with `digits:digits:00` (doesn't replace `digits:digits:digits`)

Edit: OP wanted solution with `apply` family:

```
sapply(df$v2, function(x) sub("^([0-9]+:[0-9]+)$", "\\1:00", x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(v2, lengths(gregexpr(":", v2)) == 1, paste0(v2[lengths(gregexpr(":", v2)) == 1], ":00"))
#[1] "20:05:20" "19:20:00" "15:37:35" "12:04:21" "12:45:00" "13:08:21"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` try:

```
dt[, v3 := ifelse(grepl(":\\d+:", v2), 
                 format(strptime(v2, "%H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S"), 
                 format(strptime(v2, "%H:%M"), "%H:%M:%S"))]
```

Gives:

```
   v1       v2       v3
1:  8 20:05:20 20:05:20
2:  5    19:20 19:20:00
3:  8 15:37:35 15:37:35
4:  8 12:04:21 12:04:21
5:  5    12:45 12:45:00
6:  8 13:08:21 13:08:21
```